# Selecting a field from a table in an SQL Database

Tags: c#, sql, visual-studio, crystal-reports

I have created the data source within Visual Studio, I am trying to access a field called `Reference No_` by using the Brief Number which is stored as `No_`.

```
argclean="AW02464";            
string connectionString = "Data Source=ERP-SERVER; Initial Catalog=RMS2015; Integrated Security=True";
SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
var query = "SELECT [Reference No_] FROM [RMS2015].[dbo].[RMS Live$Artwork Brief] WHERE [No_] = " + argclean + " ";
```

Above is my code that I have tried but I cant seem to get it to work

Comment: "canst seem to get it to work" doesn't mean anything. What happens? did you get an exception? Where is the code for executing the query? Why are you concatenating strings instead of using parameters?

Comment: Nothing happens at all, that's the problem. Query is never assigned a value.

Comment: where is the rest of the code? there should be an SqlCommand there to execute the query...

Answer (score 0):

It's better to get in the habit of using params in your queries, such as:

```
var query = "SELECT [Reference No_] FROM [RMS2015].[dbo].[RMS Live$Artwork Brief] WHERE [No_] = @ArtworkNumber;
```

...and then:

```
new SqlParameter()
{
    ParameterName = "@ArtworkNumber",
    SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar,
    Value = argclean
}
```

### UPDATE

Here is a general purpose method I use to retreive a DataTable from a query:

```
public static DataTable ExecuteSQLReturnDataTable(string sql, CommandType cmdType, params SqlParameter[] parameters)
{
    using (DataSet ds = new DataSet())
    using (SqlConnection connStr = new SqlConnection(YourConnStr))
    using (SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand(sql, connStr))
    {
        cmd.CommandType = cmdType;
        cmd.CommandTimeout = EXTENDED_TIMEOUT;
        foreach (var item in parameters)
        {
            cmd.Parameters.Add(item);
        }

        cmd.Connection.Open();
        new SqlDataAdapter(cmd).Fill(ds);
        return ds.Tables[0];
    }
}
```

It can be called like so:

```
DataTable dtDeliveryPerformanceResults = 
    SQLDBHelper.ExecuteSQLReturnDataTable(
        PLATYPUS_STOREDPROC,
        CommandType.StoredProcedure,
        new SqlParameter()
        {
            ParameterName = "@Unit",
            SqlDbType = SqlDbType.VarChar,
            Value = unit
        },
        new SqlParameter()
        {
            ParameterName = "@BeginDate",
            SqlDbType = SqlDbType.DateTime,
            Value = _begDate
        },
        new SqlParameter()
        {
            ParameterName = "@EndDate",
            SqlDbType = SqlDbType.DateTime,
            Value = _endDate
        },
        new SqlParameter()
        {
            ParameterName = "@PoisonToeLength",
            SqlDbType = Convert.ToInt32(SqlDbType.Int),
            Value = 42
        }
    );
```

The example shows calling a Stored Procedure (a recommended practice), but you can use it with "regular" or "plain vanilla" SQL queries, too.

Comment: I have the gut feeling that this guy doesn't create/execute the command. Perhaps you could help him adding that bit of code.